# Postman can't send post request to server and server detecting it as get request instead of post

Tags: android, spring, spring-boot, postman

Having issue in postman can't send post request to the server.
So I have

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public blablabla (@PathVariable long id )

@PostMapping("/scan")
public blablablabla(){}
```

Somehow when I send post request for `/scan` via postman it returns

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Long'; 
nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: \"scan\
```

But it works fine in my android application. 
Is this postman issue?

Thank you

Comment: you have to define the content type in postman tool before sending any request.  Refer the following link                                                                                                                    https://medium.com/aubergine-solutions/api-testing-using-postman-323670c89f6d

Comment: I've got the problem. I already defined the content type. But I send http request to my https server. That's the problem. Thank you for your support @Suresh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the answer..
In postman, I send http request to my https server.
So it's redirecting it making it a GET request instead of my POST request.